# How to find out what program took over control over Print Screen key?

Tags: windows-7, print-screen, greenshot

How to find out and change what program responds to PrintScreen key press? Right now I use Greenshot and it fails to assign "Capture region" to PrintScreen.

The error still persists:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAFxx.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The utility [Hotkey Commander](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/index.html) should be able to show which application has claimed <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>.

You might also try the following.

> **Why does the Print key not work in some windows?**
>
> If you are using Windows Vista or later and have Greenshot running
>   without admininstrator privileges, while the currently active (i.e.
>   focused) program window is running with administrator privileges,
>   Windows’ User Account Control will not notify Greenshot that the
>   <kbd>Print</kbd> key has been pressed.
>
> However there are some easy workarounds for this problem:
>
> - Run Greenshot with administrator privileges.
> - Click somewehere else (e.g. task bar) to deactivate the current window, before hitting the <kbd>Print</kbd> key.
> - Use Greenshot’s systray context menu to create a screen capture.

http://getgreenshot.org/faq/why-does-the-print-key-not-work-in-some-windows/

Comment: Not sure if this HotKey Commander program is still any good. On launch it ran the Windows Magnifier and Windows Narrator programs, using Windows 11.

Comment: This is now malware. Please don't use it.